# Ознакомляет или ознакамливает?

Tags: лексика

Есть ли в русском языке слово "ознакомляет"? Или все же правильно "ознакамливает"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском языке есть глагол *ознакомлять* (3 лицо ед.ч. - *ознакомляет*). Глагола *ознакамливать* (и формы *ознакамливает*) нет. (Полный орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. Лопатина)